# Соотношение блоков в SVG

Tags: вёрстка, svg, адаптивная-верстка

Многие блоки в SVG задаются при помощи осей X и Y. Когда блоков на странице становится больше, то как скрепить их все, чтобы при изменении размера окна относительное растояние между ними оставалось одинаковым?